# Sencha GXT Executive Dashboard

Tags: gwt, gxt

Upon downloading the latest GXT last night I got this [image] on the page that shows the "Executive Dashboard" however where in the GXT Trial can I find the "executive dashboard" in the trial package.

Is it something that is available for GXT 3.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will have the executive dashboard demo available with our GXT 4.0 release. Deployment details are still in the works.

The GXT 4.0 preview release target is Sept. 1st and the GXT 4.0 general release  target is Oct 1st. *

- The target dates are based on executive management provision and everything passes quality control. There is a possibility of some slippage of time either way, but we're working hard towards the target.